# CakePHP exception logic

Tags: cakephp, exception

I have a controller where I throw a custom exception and I have a custom exception renderer class, which extends the basic exception renderer.

Now when I throw the exception, I'd like to do some cleanup with the stuff, that went wrong and after that render a custom error page.

```
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function invalidCall($error) {
        $this->controller->render('/Errors/invalid_call');
        $this->controller->response->send();
    }

    public function incompleteCall($error) {
        $this->controller->render('/Errors/incomplete_call');
        $this->controller->response->send();
    }
}
```

The rendering works well so far. But where should I put the logic for the cleanup things?
In the exception itself? In the renderer? In the controller before throwing the exception?

Comment: What exactly is your "cleanup" code doing?

Comment: @ndm: delete some "dead" entries from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as so often there are many ways to skin a cat, but I'd say in order to stay [DRY](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself), for easy testing, and in order to stay in compliance with [the recommended **fat model** concept](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html), you should put the logic in the model.

And in order to decouple cleanup and exception handling, you could for example utilize the [event system](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html) and let the models that may need to be cleaned attach themselfs as listeners (they should know best whether they may need to be cleaned up), and let a custom error handler dispatch an appropriate event, that way the exception handler doesn't need to know about the app internals.

Here's some very basic, *untested* example code that should illustrate the idea:

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');

class ExampleModel extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Example';

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
    {
        CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(array($this, 'cleanup'), 'AppErrorHandler.beforeHandleException');
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }

    public function cleanup()
    {
        // do some magic
    }
}
?>

<?php
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'Event');
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');

class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler
{
    public static function handleException(Exception $exception)
    {
        CakeEventManager::instance()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('AppErrorHandler.beforeHandleException', get_called_class(), array($exception)));
        parent::handleException($exception);
    }
}
?>
```

**Update**

In order to be able to react to specific exceptions only, you could for example utilize the exception class name in the event name, so it would trigger events like `...beforeHandleFooBarException` to wich you could explicitly subscribe:

```
<?php
class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler
{
    public static function handleException(Exception $exception)
    {
        CakeEventManager::instance()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('AppErrorHandler.beforeHandle' . get_class($exception), get_called_class(), array($exception)));

        parent::handleException($exception);
    }
}
?>

<?php
class ExampleModel extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Example';

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
    {
        $eventManager = CakeEventManager::instance();
        $callback = array($this, 'cleanup');

        $eventManager->attach($callback, 'AppErrorHandler.beforeHandleInvalidCallException');
        $eventManager->attach($callback, 'AppErrorHandler.beforeHandleIncompleteCallException');

        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }

    public function cleanup()
    {
        // do some magic
    }
}
?>
```

If you would stick with the generic exception event, then another option would be to check the type of the exception in the models event listener callback:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
{
    CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(array($this, 'beforeHandleException'), 'AppErrorHandler.beforeHandleException', array('passParams' => true));
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}

public function beforeHandleException($exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof InvalidCallException ||
       $exception instanceof IncompleteCallException)
    {
        $this->cleanup();
    }
}

public function cleanup()
{
    // do some magic
}
```

Comment: This would not affect all other exceptions? Or do I have to write handlers for the other, too?

Comment: Right, this example would trigger the listener for every exception. If you want to bind to specific exceptions only, you could for example build the event-name based on the exception, or you could test the type of exception in the models listener callback. I'll update my answer with examples that illustrate this.